# Amcharts chart doesnt loading every page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I am using amcharts library for charting.

Amcharts sometimes doesnt load.Its loading after few page refreshing.

It doesnt any errors on console.

Here is order of chart library js:

```
<script src="js/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="js/turkeyLow.js"></script>
<script src="js/amchart_serial.js"></script>
```

what can I do for this issue?

Comment: Try including ammap_amcharts_extension.js instead of ammap.js

Comment: In that case you will need to provide a link, a standalone demo or something similar, so that we have a chance of figuring it out.