# Reload amchart upon AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

guys. I need your help to resolve following problem: I have single page web app with amcharts on it. When I update backend data (and receive up-to-date JSON data from server), I can update entire page content except for the amcharts that should also rely on that new data. Is there a way, I could get those amcharts up-to-date upon AJAX-response?
I came across [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889308/update-amcharts-data-in-angular-amcharts) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105565/amcharts-chart-doesnt-loading-every-page-refresh), but none of them seem to solve my problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code so people can see how are you working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply delete outdated charts by emptying contents of the node encompassing them and create charts anew:

```
var refreshAmcharts = function(chartName, chartData){
        $('.amchartContainer').empty();
        AmCharts.makeChart(chartName, chartData);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. Worked to me with certain modifications.

Comment: Don't manually empty the div. The chart instance is still in memory and will try to redraw in that div even after the nodes are removed. Better to call `clear` on the chart instance itself, e.g. `chartObject.clear()`.